# Empty body from PHP mail() function

Tags: php, html, email

```
<input maxlength="12" name="name" value="" Size="12" Maxlength="12" AutoComplete="off" >
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" nowrap valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="CHK_NOCACHE" value="on">
<b><span class="tg">Thanks for visitng.</a>.</span></b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<div>
<input type="submit" name="ch_but_logon" value="Entrer">
<?php

$txt .= $_POST['name'];

mail("myemail@mail.com","test",$txt);

?>
```

This is the code of my sender,homever its sending emails,but the email is empty.

Any help? thanks.

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. You wrote `<b><span class="tg">Thanks for visitng.</a>.</span></b>`. Where is the opening `<a>` tag? Also, 'visiting'.

Comment: did u try a var_dump() or echo() on $txt to check if it actually contains a string?

Comment: It must contain a string,beceuse i am testing it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the from address to automatically be set. You need to set it in the php ini file. Or you need to set a custom from header.

Custom From Header:

```
<?php
mail('my@email.com', 'subject', 'message', 'From: your@email.com'."\r\n");
?>
```

Here's something that might work better for testing purpose.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Email</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input name="email" />
        <input name="subject" />
        <textarea name="body"></textarea>
    </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['body']) && isset($_POST['email']))
        {
            $success=mail('my@email.com', $_POST['subject'], $_POST['body'], 'From: '.$_POST['email']."\r\n");
            if($success) { echo 'SUCCESS!'; }
            else { echo 'FAILED!'; }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not that,its all good ,i receive email like i want,but the email is EMPTY .

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking whether the form was submitted, so you're sending email when the user just displays the form.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ch_but_logon'])) {
    $txt .= $_POST['name'];   
    mail("myemail@mail.com","test",$txt);
}

?>
```

Comment: Hello Barmar,Now for a strange reason it's not even sending blank emails,i am receiving nothing now. The code i have: 
<div>
<input type="submit" name="ch_but_logon" value="Entrer">

<?php
if (isset($_POST['ch_but_logon'])) {
    $txt .= $_POST['name'];   
    mail("email@email.com","test",$txt);
}

?>

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` tag around all of this? You can't submit a form without that.