# PHP mail function is not sending any messages

Tags: php, html, email

I'm confused with what the problem is, I'm not receiving any e-mail whilst using the `mail` php function.

**PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ch_but_logon'])) {
    $txt .= $_POST['named23'];   
    mail("email@email.com","test",$txt);
}

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="mailer.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="named23" size="12">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" nowrap valign="top">
    <input type="checkbox" name="CHK_NOCACHE" value="on">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <div>
      <input type="submit" name="ch_but_logon" value="Entrer">
```

@@@@UPDATE@@@@

updated code : Index

```
<form action="mailer.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="named23" size="12">
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" nowrap valign="top">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CHK_NOCACHE" value="on">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div>
        <input type="submit" name="ch_but_logon" value="Entrer">
</form>
```

MAILER.PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ch_but_logon'])) {
    $txt = $_POST['named23'];   
    mail("psadsaxu@yahoo.sds","test",$txt);
}

?>
```

But now again,it's not sending email. Not receiving anything.

Comment: Seems like you haven't closed your `<form>` tag at the end?

Comment: You just posted another question where you wrote that you _are_ getting email, but the body is empty. Which is it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591758/empty-body-from-php-mail-function

Comment: Bakmar,before the body was empty beceuse the code was sending the email instantly when user enters the website,but for now i modified with your help,and i am not receiving the email anymore

Comment: I'm not sure if your on a test server, but I'd recommend downloading [SMTP4Dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/), it will replicate a live SMTP Server.

Comment: The server is working correctly,tested another email sender and it worked.

Comment: Be careful. You should validate that styring.

Answer (score 0):

You need close `</form>` at the end of the code, because all inputs should be include within form, specially `<input type="submit" name="ch_but_logon" value="Entrer">` that are used to validate in your PHP `if (isset($_POST['ch_but_logon'])) {`

And you need remove "dot" before "equals" symbol because **$txt** was't created before, and this concat operation are unnecessary:

```
$txt = $_POST['named23'];
```

Comment: updated code : Index
`<form action="mailer.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="named23" size="12">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" nowrap valign="top">
<input type="checkbox" name="CHK_NOCACHE" value="on">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<div>
<input type="submit" name="ch_but_logon" value="Entrer">
</form>`

MAILER.PHP
`<?php
if (isset($_POST['ch_but_logon'])) {
    $txt = $_POST['named23'];   
    mail("psadsaxu@yahoo.sds","test",$txt);
}

?>`
But now again,it's not sending email. Not receiving anything.

Comment: Please update your original question!

Comment: Question updated,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid. You can't have `<td>` and `<tr>` outside the form, but `</tr>` and `</td>` inside the form. These tags have to be nested properly. When you don't nest correctly, the browser will add all the necessary end tags to the inner tags. The result of this is that your form is ending after the `named23` element, and the checkbox and submit button are not part of the form.

You should put the entire table inside the `<form>...</form>` tags.

Comment: Just did,and it's same , not receiving anything.

Comment: Have you verified that the script is running? If you add `var_dump($_POST);` to it, what does it display? Have you checked your mail log?